# AJAX Filter WHILE Loop not working Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have made a AJAX Filter with Wordpress, but my loop is not working.
Who can help me with this?

I try to get custom fields back that i use with ACF.

```
 function filter_reports() {
   global $customer_account;
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'ebooks',
     'tax_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'customer',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => $customer_account,
       ),
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'disease',
         'field'    => 'term_id',
         'terms'    => $_POST['options'],
       )
     ),
   );



$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$results = array();

   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $id =  get_the_ID();
      array_push($results, array(
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => get_field('title', $id),
        'chair' => get_field('e-chair', $id),
      ));
    }
  }

  echo json_encode($results);
  die;

}
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter_reports', 'filter_reports' );
```

Comment: two things, ajax should `return` things not echo you are not echo array for God's sake , and you are missing wp_ajax_nopriv_... probable.

Comment: So what should i do?

I am learning.

Comment: Writing you a reply...

Comment: Please consider my answer, as most helpful for now, since no other replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should organize your code to return things from Ajax call.
If this should work for any user you need to use also `wp_ajax_nopriv_...`

However, I would use `dionoh_filter_reports` action name.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dionoh_filter_reports', 'filter_reports' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dionoh_filter_reports', 'filter_reports' );
```

I suggest you check [this](https://pippinsplugins.com/process-ajax-requests-correctly-in-wordpress-plugins/) and learn more.

Comment: I still get an 500 error.

Comment: There is something going on within my loop i think.

Comment: Please narrow down your problems and ask the new question. I already provided you few tips to improve your Ajax skills in WordPress. Be fair and report all things you get such as error 500 in the new question.